# Библиотека PdfKit не читает русские символы

Tags: node.js, pdf, кодировка, fstream, buffer

```
var doc = new PDFDocument;

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output1.pdf',   {flags: 'w', encoding: 'binary',mode: 0666}));
doc.fontSize(15);
doc.font('Times-Bold').text('Привет');
doc.font('Times-Bold').text('Hello');
doc.end();
```

Код идеально работает для Английского языка, а в пдф возвращает 'Aô@C„KD"'
и др. cимволы.

Я пробовала менять дефолтовый значения createWriteStream - не помогло. Предложения?

Comment: Please use russian in russian forum

Comment: Вопросы на ruSO принято задавать на русском языке. Отредактируйте свой вопрос.

Comment: А вы уверены, что у шрифта `Times-Bold` есть русские шрифты? а то первая [ссылка](http://fonts.mega8.ru/index.php?font=8092&name=Times%20Bold) показывает, что нет в нем кириллицы.